# Statistical analysis of variable data

Tags: statistical-significance

I have the statistical research data. I have 6 treatments with 3 boxes for each treatment. I am raining on the treatments every week and collecting data. The data is variable within boxes and also with time. For eg: on 20 July, value for seeded treatment was 4500 and after the end of August, the value becomes 2000 with the increase in vegetation. The standard deviation of the treatment for the whole study period is sometimes more than mean due to higher variability. the sample size for the whole study period is close to 350. The data comes out to be normal. out of 6 treatments, 4 treatments have very lower values than other 2 treatments. for eg: 4 treatments have the values in range of 50-500 and other 2 have the values in range of 2200-2500. When I performed Tukey Kramer on all 6 treatments, there is no significance among the 4 treatments. When I apply Tukey Kramer on just the 4 low value treatments, there is some significance among the treatments. How is it possible? What exact analysis or test can I perform on this kind of data? I would be highly obliged if someone has some suggestions or solutions. I need to defend soon and i need to finish this statistical analysis. Data is a non uniform time series data also and I don't know which statistical analysis or test need to be performed on this kind of data. I am really confused. I will really appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Needs to be clarified and reorganized.

Answer (score 0):

Repeated-measures ANOVA is a possibility. Not clear: “data is variable within boxes and also with time”, where there multiple subsamples at each time point?

Since Tukey test corrects for experiment-wise error rate, reducing the SE, eg dropping the two treatments as described above, can increase the test statistic/decrease the p-value.

It is not unheard of to follow up an ANOVA with multiple treatment levels by another one, where the ‘larger’ and the ‘smaller’ groups are compared. It is not very prudent, because it reformulates the question after testing, but not impossible.

Comment: I am very curious: what about the assumptions of Tukey (or ANOVA), does Sid have to care about them? For example, the assumption about within and among sample independence seems to be violated, as something is growing over the time. Also, what about homogeneity? What if these 2 very large treatments will have much larger variance than small ones?

Comment: @PauliusŠarka - right, that's why 'repeated measures' (to account for non-independence, a regular ANOVA is certainly not an option) and 'a possibility' (to account for potentially violated assumptions - thanks for specifying).